# In the definition of the Heegard Floer surgery exact triangle, what exactly is the correspondence between Whitney triangles and periodic domains?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, 3-manifolds, heegaard-floer-homology

I'm reading [Osváth-Szabó's notes on Heegard Floer homology](http://math.mit.edu/~petero/Lectures.pdf), in particular about the surgery exact triangle.

On page 14 (numbered 42 on the document), they describe an isomorphism between the space of homology classes of Whitney triangles $\pi_2(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y},\mathbf{z})$ in $\mbox{Sym}^g(\Sigma)$ and $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathcal{P} $, where $\mathcal{P}$ denotes the group of periodic domains in $\Sigma$.

I'm not sure if I understand this isomorphism correctly, or if there are some typos, or both. Here is how I understand the isomorphism works:

Given two elements $\psi, \psi_0 \in \pi_2(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y},\mathbf{z})$, we can associate domains $\mathcal{D}(\psi), \mathcal{D}(\psi_0)$, by taking $$\mathcal{D}(\psi) = \sum n_{z_i}(\psi) D_i,$$

where $D_i$ are the components of $\Sigma - \{\mathbf{\alpha} \cup \mathbf{\beta}\cup\mathbf{\gamma}\}$, and $z_i \in D_i$; and $n_{z_i}(\psi)$ is the algebraic intersection of $\psi$ with $z_i \times \mbox{sym}^{g-1}(\Sigma)$.

It follows that if $n_z(\psi) = n_z(\psi_0)$, the domain $E = \mathcal{D}(\psi) - \mathcal{D}(\psi_0)$ is periodic: *i.e.* it satisfies $n_z(E) = 0$ (here, $n_z(E)$ denotes the coefficient of the component of $\Sigma - \{\mathbf{\alpha} \cup \mathbf{\beta}\cup\mathbf{\gamma}\}$ containing $z$ in $E$).

So all we have to do to define the isomorphism is pick a $\psi_0$ such that $n_z(\psi_0) = 1$: then we can subtract off $n \mathcal{D}(\psi_0)$ from $\mathcal{D}(\psi)$ to get a periodic domain. Given a fixed $\psi_0$, the isomorphism is then given by

$$\psi \mapsto (n, \mathcal{D}(\psi) - n\mathcal{D}(\psi_0)).$$

The inverse of the isomorphism should then be given by sending $(n, E)$ to something like $n \psi_0 + \phi$, where $\mathcal{D}(\phi) = E$; but this seems dependent on choice and I'm not entirely sure how to make sense of $n$ times a holomorphic triangle.

Is this right? How do I fix the last part?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I had to guess, I'd go for the typo *and* a small misunderstanding.

I think that the isomorphism should indeed depend on the choice of a triangle $\psi_0$ with $n_z(\psi_0) = 0$ (careful here: this has to be 0 and not 1, as you wrote above), but that it should be defined as

$$\psi\mapsto (n_z(\psi), \mathcal{D}(\psi)-\mathcal{D}(\psi_0)-n_z(\psi)\cdot\Sigma)$$

whose inverse is given by (notice that now you only sum a triangle and some periodic domain, plus multiples of the Heegaard surface)

$$(n,P)\mapsto \psi_0 + P + n\Sigma$$

The isomorphism I gave above agrees with the isomorphism in the notes only for domains with $n_z = 0$ (which are the only ones you consider in the hat version).

---

I don't think that you need a canonical choice for $\psi_0$ (hence for the isomorphism), nor that it's possible to have one.

One final remark: here you're not really summing *holomorphic triangles*, but rather *domains*, so you shouldn't worry about the "holomorphic meaning" of the sum of domains.

Comment: Thanks for this. I knew there was something fishy going on with $n_z(\psi)$ not being one, but not how to fix it. With regards to your final remark, I understand what you're saying: I suppose what I'm wondering is how  one goes from domain to holomorphic triangle: i.e. is there an easy way to see that every domain can be realised as $\mathcal{D}(\psi)$ for some $\psi$? For instance, what is $\psi$ for $n \Sigma$?

Comment: No, there's no easy way to do that in general. I think that for the hat version you can reduce everything to combinatorics (at the cost of increasing dramatically the number of generators) -- this is surely the case if you care about discs instead of triangles.

Comment: I can post a separate question, but why is the difference $E=\mathcal{D}(\psi)-\mathcal{D}(\psi_0)-n_z(\psi)\cdot \Sigma$ periodic? I see why $n_z(E)=0$, but why is $\partial E$ a sum of the attaching circles (and not just partial segments of them)?

Comment: Look at the $\alpha$-boundary $\partial_\alpha E$ of $E$, i.e. the boundary of the $\alpha$ portion of the boundary of $E$; $\partial_\alpha$ is linear, hence $\partial_\alpha E$ is the sum of the $\alpha$-boundaries of the three summands. The first two summands have opposite $\partial_\alpha$ by definition, and the third has no $\alpha$-boundary.

Comment: Thanks. That must be what I'm missing -- why does $\partial_\alpha(\mathcal{D}(\psi))=\partial_\alpha(\mathcal{D}(\psi_0))$?

Comment: $\psi$ and $\psi_0$ both live in $\pi_2(x,y,z)$, hence they have the same $\alpha$-boundary (as well as $\beta$- and $\gamma$-).